# How do I use Group By based on a Case statement in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case

I have an SQL-query where I use Oracle `CASE` to compare if a date column is *less than* or *greater than* current date. But how do I use that `CASE`-statement in a `GROUP BY`-statement? I would like to count the records in each case.

E.g.

```
select
    (case
        when exp_date > sysdate then 1
        when exp_date <= sysdate then 2
        else 3
     end) expired, count(*)
from mytable
group by expired
```

But I get an error when trying this: `ORA-00904`. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268429/group-by-alias-oracle

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
select
(case
    when exp_date > sysdate then 1
    when exp_date <= sysdate then 2
    else 3
 end) expired, count(*)
from mytable
group by (case
    when exp_date > sysdate then 1
    when exp_date <= sysdate then 2
    else 3
 end)
```

Comment: what the difference with the in-line view in terms of performances ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Would depend on whether oracle evaluates the `CASE` twice. You could check using `EXPLAIN PLAN`. In any case, with hindsight, I'd probably go with @Ollie answer, as I think the SQL looks better without the duplicated logic

Comment: What if I want 1,2,3 as column Header, how should I write the sql?

Answer (score 29):

Use an inline view:

```
SELECT expired,
       count(*)
  FROM (SELECT (CASE
                   WHEN exp_date > SYSDATE THEN 1
                   WHEN exp_date <= SYSDATE THEN 2
                   ELSE 3
                 END) AS expired
          FROM mytable)
GROUP BY expired;
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

As an additional input, although it does not relate to this thread, you can also aggregate your case statements without mentioning it in the group by clause.

```
SELECT
   WORK_ORDER_NUMBER,
   SUM(CASE WHEN STOCK_CODE LIKE 'xxxx' THEN STOCK_QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL
FROM Table
GROUP BY WORK_ORDER_NUMBER;
```