# Oracle Sql Query : Error Query on SUM()

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

i want sum() some column. but does'nt work. it's error ORA-00937
please help me.

**Query**

```
SELECT MB.COUNTRY_CODE, /* Error ORA-00937 This line */
       MB.OPERATOR_NAME AS COUNTRY_NAME,
       C.PMN_CODE AS OPERATOR_NAME,
       (C.RANG_START / 1024) AS RANG_START,
       (C.RANG_END / 1024) AS RANG_END,
       COUNT(*) AS TRANSACTION_BY_OPER,
       '0' AS TERMINATE_CHARGE,
       SUM(C.RATE * (COUNT(*))) AS TRANSIT_CHARGE       
  FROM IR_V_IMM_RATE_BY_CDR C 
  LEFT JOIN IR_PMN_MASTER_BROKER MB 
    ON C.COMPANY_CODE = MB.COMPANY_CODE 
   AND C.PMN_DOMAIN = MB.PMN_CODE
  LEFT JOIN IR_PMN_INTER_SERVICE S 
    ON C.PMN_DOMAIN = S.PMN_CODE 
   AND C.COMPANY_CODE = S.COMPANY_CODE
  WHERE C.SUB_EVENT_TYPE_ID = '2'
   AND C.MODIFIER = 'P2P'
   AND S.INTER_SERVICE = 'MMS'
   AND C.COMPANY_CODE = 'AIS'
   AND C.EVENT_TYPE_ID = '602'
   AND C.PMN_DOMAIN = 'AICEN'
   AND TO_CHAR(C.CUTOFF_DATE, 'MM/YYYY') = '04/2015'
  GROUP BY MB.COUNTRY_CODE, MB.OPERATOR_NAME, C.PMN_CODE, C.RANG_START,  
           C.RANG_END, C.RATE
```

**if delete 3 line. it's work**

```
COUNT(*) AS TRANSACTION_BY_OPER,
'0' AS TERMINATE_CHARGE,
SUM(C.RATE * (COUNT(*))) AS TRANSIT_CHARGE
....
...
/* Fix If delete 3 line */
GROUP BY MB.COUNTRY_CODE, MB.OPERATOR_NAME,C.PMN_CODE,C.RANG_START,C.RANG_END
```

now, i want add 3 line in this query. but Error ORA-00937

thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: try including   TERMINATE_CHARGE, in group by and check..include all fields in group by which is not inside an aggregate function at select statement

Comment: Change the name to Operator_Name2 and see if it works `C.PMN_CODE AS OPERATOR_NAME,`  I think it may be conflicting with `MB.Operator_name` in group by

Comment: You `SUM(C.RATE` and you `GROUP BY C.RATE`...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268429/group-by-alias-oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
  SUM(C.RATE * (COUNT(*))) AS TRANSIT_CHARGE
```

Nesting aggregation functions (generally) doesn't work.  You probably just want:

```
  SUM(C.RATE) AS TRANSIT_CHARGE
```

This adds up all the rates on the rows generated before the `group by`.

Comment: Thanks! I try delete count(). it's work. but result calculate number not required. thanks u so much. ;D

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MB.COUNTRY_CODE, /* Error ORA-00937 This line */
       MB.OPERATOR_NAME AS COUNTRY_NAME,
       C.PMN_CODE AS OPERATOR_NAME,
       (C.RANG_START / 1024) AS RANG_START,
       (C.RANG_END / 1024) AS RANG_END,
       COUNT(*) AS TRANSACTION_BY_OPER,
       '0' AS TERMINATE_CHARGE,
       SUM(C.RATE * (COUNT(*))) AS TRANSIT_CHARGE       
  FROM IR_V_IMM_RATE_BY_CDR C 
  LEFT JOIN IR_PMN_MASTER_BROKER MB 
    ON C.COMPANY_CODE = MB.COMPANY_CODE 
   AND C.PMN_DOMAIN = MB.PMN_CODE
  LEFT JOIN IR_PMN_INTER_SERVICE S 
    ON C.PMN_DOMAIN = S.PMN_CODE 
   AND C.COMPANY_CODE = S.COMPANY_CODE
  WHERE C.SUB_EVENT_TYPE_ID = '2'
   AND C.MODIFIER = 'P2P'
   AND S.INTER_SERVICE = 'MMS'
   AND C.COMPANY_CODE = 'AIS'
   AND C.EVENT_TYPE_ID = '602'
   AND C.PMN_DOMAIN = 'AICEN'
   AND TO_CHAR(C.CUTOFF_DATE, 'MM/YYYY') = '04/2015'
  GROUP BY MB.COUNTRY_CODE, MB.OPERATOR_NAME, C.PMN_CODE, C.RANG_START,  
           C.RANG_END,'0'
```

You are including `'0'` and it is not included in group by and it is neither in aggregate function. Also remove `C.Rate` from group by because it is using inside aggregate function `Sum`.try this